# Conditional Tags If Custom Post Parent & Child?

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags, single

Check on the single-artists.php whether we are viewing the parent or child of the said custom post?

Tried this but always shows the top child content, rather then showing the two different area

```
<?php if ('artists' == get_post_type()  || $post->post_parent=='artists') { ?>

           the child single-artists.php

<?php } else { ?>

           the parent single-artists.php


<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post_parent is a numerical value field in $post object. So you should check if there's a valid number. Try this -

```
<?php if ( $post->post_parent > 0 ) { ?>
    the child single-artists.php
<?php } else { ?>
    the parent single-artists.php
<?php } ?>
```